# Does goftp package provide for secure file transfers?

Tags: ssh, ftp, go, sftp, ftp-client

Im working on a project that is currently using goftp found in [`goftp`](https://github.com/jlaffaye/goftp)  to upload some files into a website directory where it is used and viewed by the website.

I am know questioning the security of this setup, so I have looked into ssh and sftp for golang, but I'm running into problems and it's just a big headache, since I'm new with golang.

My question is, what are the security threats or problems of just using [`goftp`](https://github.com/jlaffaye/goftp) and are there more secure alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If goftp is using the FTP protocol, then yes, it's insecure (plain text passwords,...)

Comment: Not ony passwords are transferred in plain text but the protocol does not mitigate [MitM attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All plain FTP servers are inherently insecure as they authenticate using plain text over an unencrypted link. This means that anyone on the same network (in particular WiFi networks) can sniff the network traffic and easily extract the username and password used to authenticate.

You've already mentioned some of the recommended alternatives, SSH and SFTP. SSH provides the means to use SCP to transfer files securely. SFTP also uses the underlying transport provided by SSH. There is also FTPS which uses standard FTP over an SSL encrypted connection.

Have a look at [this link](http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/75602/Understanding-Key-Differences-Between-FTP-FTPS-and-SFTP) for more information on the differences between the protocols.

In researching Go libraries for FTP I came across [a mention](https://plus.google.com/100668783035075698145/posts/VidPsn47iDm) that the github.com/jlaffaye/goftp library breaks on multi-line responses.

It's highly recommended to use a more secure protocol than plain FTP so you would be better served by looking at SCP/SFTP/FTPS solutions. Here's a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/jedy/3357393) claiming to be an example of using SCP in Go. That could be a good starting point.

Comment: the last gist is buggy. the author clains it in some other question that it is buggy. also goroutine started in the end is definitely buggy.